# Pip recommended structure

Tags: python, deployment, python-3.x, pip

Now that "pip" is going to be included with Python 3.4, could anyone knowledgeable share the recommended way of setting up a project? For example, the file structure and the content of "setup.py", if it is still needed?

Lets say, there is:

```
+ - + - Parent Folder
    |
    + - + - project
    |   |
    |   + - __init__.py
    |
    + - README
    |
    + - COPYING
```

Answer (score 1):

`setup.py` should be in the same directory as `README`. I say this because simply including `pip` in the python 3.4 installation should change nothing in how it operates.

I say this from experience, because I've had to install many libraries from source, and `setup.py` was *always* in the same directory as `README`. Simple adding by default in a python distribution changes nothing.